# How to make APK available only for Tablets in Google Play Store with Delphi XE 10.3.1 Rio?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

It is possible to make one `Android APK` only for tablets with Delphi XE10.3.1 Rio?

Thank you.

Comment: This may help you .https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution

Comment: @ramyabr thank you.